# How to make sure your admin doesn't hi-jack you site?

Tags: admin, wp-admin, user-roles

I have a domain and I would like to hire someone to develop it. Could it be possible to give him full control, yet be safe that he does not hi-jack the site. Or the only way is for me to be the admin and add him as a user with increased privileges? Is there any other way one can give control to someone else, yet be safe? 
Furthermore, shouldn't he also have access to cpanel (for backup etc.)? Does this mean I should create a new hosting account?

I guess what I'm actually asking is how to let a guy create and manage a wp site for you and still be as safe as possible.

Comment: Erm, if you don't trust the developer, don't work with them.

Comment: Good point, but in the age of outsourcing it is not always possible to build absolute trust. I'm looking for someone to be in charge of the site, planning and posting articles etc., not just setting it up.

Comment: then don't do outsourcing ;)

Answer (score 1):

Age-old question I guess.

Hire someone who, you think, and can understand, is a good fit for you according to their portfolio and past activity. To this day, tracking someone is not that tough. Simply follow them for some days in their social network, and you can sum up something. Even you can [sometimes] verify their portfolio images using google's image search using an image. (I'm suggesting these to someone who is desperate ☺️)

Take a backup of all your things before taking a developer or an active development *in*. cPanel grants FTP access; make a FTP access only for your developer, and it can even be restricted to specific subdomain or add-on domain.

If they destroy your site, revoke their access and deploy your site from backup. If they somehow spoil your cPanel access, contact to the vendor and get your access back by resetting password.  (Still, I'm suggesting these to someone who is desperate ☺️)

As you said in comment:

> I'm looking for someone to be in charge of the site, planning and posting articles etc., not just setting it up.

WordPress has lesser privilege user accounts, create one with `contributor` or `author` privilege and give them the account to do some site follow up and article posting etc.

And controlling privileges for them time-by-time is very handy using plugin like this [User Role Editor](https://wordpress.org/plugins/user-role-editor/) or [Members](https://wordpress.org/plugins/members/).

---

But always, do trust someone who is trust-worthy. I found trust is everything. Pick someone; *not* just Hire one.

Comment: all code is bug free until they are found and all humans are trust worthy until you discover that they are not. If you think following someone on FB/twitter will tell you if as a side job he leaves backdoors in the sites he manages/developes then you are naive, and good backdoors are virtually impossible to detect.

Comment: @MarkKaplun very well said. I know all the mentioned processes are so dumb. And I never tried someone to restrict whom I'm saying a 'developer'. I believe, simply trust them, because they knows the way, I not. So one way I'm restricting them, I'm simply saying: *do take the other way*. I appreciate your comment.